# is Gatling multiple protocol execution possible

Tags: apache-kafka, gatling, scala-gatling

There's a requirement to execute two Gatling scenarios in two protocols. For an example I need to send some Kafka  events to two separate Kafka topics. since the Kafka topic is sets to protocol level I need to use two protocols with parallel execution. Does anyone know whether its possible or not. I'm expecting like below.

```
 setUp(
scn
  .inject(rampUsersPerSec(1).to(60).during(10 minutes),
    constantUsersPerSec(60).during(60 minutes),
    rampUsersPerSec(60).to(1).during(10 minutes))
.protocols(kafkaConfTopic_1),
scn2
  .inject(rampUsersPerSec(1).to(60).during(10 minutes),
    constantUsersPerSec(60).during(60 minutes),
    rampUsersPerSec(60).to(1).during(10 minutes))
.protocols(kafkaConfTopic_2))
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, yes. That's exactly what's in the documentation: https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/core/simulation/#protocols-configuration

Comment: hi. i received below error.

22:20:43.474 [main] ERROR io.gatling.app.Gatling$ - Run crashed
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)

 I'm using gatling 3.5.1 version

Comment: i got Below error also @stéphane-landelle


Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: setUp can only be called once
        at io.gatling.core.scenario.Simulation.setUp(Simulation.scala:48)
        at io.gatling.core.scenario.Simulation.setUp(Simulation.scala:44)
        at com.wiley.edpub.kafka.EventHubLoadTest.<init>(EventHubLoadTest.scala:147)
        ... 10 more

Comment: "I'm using gatling 3.5.1 version" => 2 years old. Current version is 3.8.4. Please upgrade.

Comment: "setUp can only be called once" => exactly. setUp can't be called multiple times. In both your example in this question and in the documentation I linked, it's only called once.

Comment: Hi Stephane, Thanks for the update. version cannot updated since kafka client libraries supports only 3.5.1

Comment: Thanks for the support Stephane. i was able to fix the issue.

Comment: "version cannot updated since kafka client libraries supports only 3.5.1" Probably because you're using an outdated/abandoned plugin, see https://github.com/Tinkoff/gatling-kafka-plugin